# Convert a Navision Filter to SQL where

Tags: t-sql, filter, navision, dynamics-nav

I have a field in table in next format `1_2..1_10|1_6|1_8|` where `1_2..1_10` include `1_2`, `1_3` and other.

How I can select data, where `number = 1_3`?

Comment: and you can't change the db structure ? This one is particulary awful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st suggestion:** Get rights to modify the db structure and figure out how to better store the Navision string.

**2nd suggestion:** CLR

I'll assume you are relatively comfortable with each of these concepts.  If you aren't they are very well documented all over the web.

My approach would be to use a CLR function as there's going to be some high level things that are awkward in SQL that C# takes care of quite easily.  The psuedo walk through would go something like this.

**Implementation**

1. Create a CLR funciton and implement it on the SQL server instance.
2. Using SQL resultset change the query to look for the returned value of the CLR function based on the navision filter value where "1_3".

**CLR Function Logic**

1. Create a c# function that takes in the value of the filter field and returns a string value.
2. The CLR function splits the filter field by the | char into a list.
3. Inside the CLR function create a second list.  Iterate over the first list.  When you find a ranged string split it on the ".." and manually add every available value between the range to the second list.  When you find a value that isnt' ranged simply add it to the second list.
4. Join the contents of the second list together on the "|" charecter.
5. Return the joined value.

**SQL Logic**

```
SELECT Field1,Field2...CLRFunctionName(FilterValue) AS FixedFilterValue FROM Sometable WHERE FixedFilterValue LIKE '%1_3%';
```

Comment: I'll note that I considered using functions inside SQL server but I think you are going to take a larger performance hit with the amount of temp tables inside the function call per row.  C# and .NET should process this iterative type thought process faster than SQL Server would.  And further before you embark on this note that CLR's can be difficult to implement properly and can be tough to maintain once they are implemented.

Comment: And one more note.  If your database is large, forget getting this query back in any kind of hurry.  Its going to be quite slow.  As I stated the best bet is to find some way to get that navision filter paired down to something easier for SQL to chew on.